# Given the URL of Page A, how can I see what other pages have featured in sessions that Page A has?

Tags: google-analytics

My end goal is to find related pages for any given input page, using 'other pages viewed in a session' as a proxy.

So given the URL of '/mens/sweatshirts', I wanted to know that there are usually always views recorded on '/mens/sweatshirts', '/mens/hoodies' and '/mens/t-shirts' for example

Any direction appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [segments](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en#:%7E:text=Next%20steps-,Introduction,specific%20part%20of%20your%20site.).

Your setup would be something like this:
Say you're working with the google demo account and was looking at men's shirts:
[image]

You would note that URL and use it in the segment configuration like so (make sure it is 'session' at first, use 'user' if you want to isolate it by the user across multiple sessions ):
[image]

Apply the segment and now all the data you see when browsing around GA will be focused only on people who have visited that men's t-shirt page. In this specific example, it shows all the pages people visit in sessions that visited the men's t-shirt page.
[image]